# Saving multiple Numpy arrays to a Numpy binary file (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, binaryfiles

I want to save multiple large-sized numpy arrays to a numpy binary file to prevent my code from crashing, but it seems like it keeps getting overwritten when I add on an array. The last array saved is what is set to allarrays when save.npy is opened and read. Here is my code:

```
with open('save.npy', 'wb') as f:
     for num in range(500):
          array = np.random.rand(100,400)
          np.save(f, array)

with open('save.npy', 'rb') as f:
     allarrays = np.load(f)
```

If the file existed before, I want it to be overwritten if the code is rerun. That's why I chose 'wb' instead of 'ab'.

Comment: All your code is doing is writing over the previously saved arrays. You can either create one array containing all of your data, or create a dataset using [h5py](https://www.h5py.org/)

Comment: I can't create one array containing all my data since it starts to crash when it gets too high, especially for image files that are relatively hefty in size (40mb per file, 500+ of them). The library I use in regards to "converting" my arrays instead of randomly generating one (as shown here) is a C-extension library and seems to crash for some files when the size is too large with many files. Would h5py help with that?

Comment: My idea would be to save the converted arrays to the numpy binary file since every time I convert the arrays to save memory space and put it in disk space temporarily.

Comment: Yes you can create a dataset for each individual filename and read/write accordingly

Comment: h5py datasets will be much faster than numpy files too

Comment: Check out `np.savez` - you can use it for multiple arrays.

Comment: While you can `np.save` repeatedly to an open file (or one reopened in `append` mode), the arrays are just stuck on to the file, one after the other.  Reading requires an equal number of `load.  There's not 'random' or 'selective' access.  This is making use of a `feature` of `save/load`; it isn't documented or `designed` for that.  `savez` or writing to separate files is more reliable.

Comment: @vlovero Not about speed foresay, but memory. I want to use the minimum amount of memory possible during runtime to prevent crashing by pushing it to diskspace and then opening it up again towards the end of the function.

Comment: @alaniwi @hpaulj `np.savez` does do multiple arrays at once, but I want to do my numpy array conversion then save right away. That's why I chose `np.save` instead. If you have 500+ files, how would you do that with `np.savez`? Would I have to do it in small batches?

Comment: @researchnewbie Sorry, don't know - only really tried it for proof of concept, not used it "in anger" on large scale.

Answer (score 3):

```
 alist =[]
 with open('save.npy', 'rb') as f: 
      alist.append(np.load(f))
```

When you load you have collect all loads in a list or something.  `load` only loads one array, starting at the current file position.

Comment: and then I would convert `alist` to a numpy array afterwards? My final array that I need to return would be like 500x500x500 as an example

Answer (score 2):

You can try memory mapping to disk.

```
# merge arrays using memory mapped file
mm = np.memmap("mmap.bin", dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=(500,100,400))
for num in range(500):
    mm[num::] = np.random.rand(100,400)

# save final array to npy file
with open('save.npy', 'wb') as f:
    np.save(f, mm[::])
```

Comment: How would the performance be to both memory mapping it and save as numpy file? I noticed memory mapping is limited to 2.5gb. What if the files were larger than that? Would I just do the same as shown, but multiple save/loads?

Comment: The 2.5 gb limit is for 32 bit systems and that would be the limit for any file (mmap or npy). In this case, you could use the same memmap file for each array then save each array to a different npy file.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem as well, and solved it in not a very neat way, but perhaps it's useful for others. It's inspired by hpaulj's approach, which is incomplete (i.e., doesn't load the data). Perhaps this is not how one is supposed to solve this problem to begin with...but anyhow, read on.

I had saved my data using a similar procedure as the OP,

```
# Saving the data in a for-loop
with open(savefilename, 'wb') as f:
    for datafilename in list_of_datafiles:
        # Do the processing
        data_to_save = ...
        np.save( savefilename, data_to_save )
```

And ran into the problem that calling `np.load()` only loaded the last saved array, none of the rest. However, I knew that the data was in principle contained in the `*.npy` file, given the file size was growing during the saving loop. What was required was to simply loop over the content of the numpy array while calling the load command repeatedly. As I didn't quite know how many files were contained in the file, I simply looped over the loading loop until it failed. It's hacky, but it works.

```
# Loading the data in a for-loop
data_to_read = []
with open(savefilename, 'r') as f:
    while True:
        try:
            data_to_read.append( np.load(f) )
        except:
            print("all data has been read!")
            break
```

Then you can call, e.g., `len(data_to_read)` to see how many of the arrays are contained in it. Calling, e.g., `data_to_read[0]` gives you the first saved array, etc.